# How can I change the computer's time by starting and ending a program?

Tags: batch-file, time

I'm trying to make a small Batch file which will start a program and change the time of my computer, and change the time back if the program shuts down.

My program isn't really working so I'm asking your help. Here's what I have got so far:

```
:Item_1
tzutil /s "Hawaiian Standard Time"

:Item_2
tzutil /s "W. Europe Standard Time"

@echo off
Start ""  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe"
set Programma="C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe"
tasklist |find /i "%Programma%"nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
'%t%' == '%t%' GOTO Item_%1%
) else (
'%t%' == '%t%' GOTO Item_%2%
)
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like some kind of a cracked version of the software you want to start (seen that a lot along with "Don't connect to the internet when asked for registration"). May I ask what you need such changes for? It seems a little bit too much to change system time in order to execute a game. System time is not something that you should tinker with under normal circumstances and gaming is one of those.

Answer (score 0):

`goto` is just, what it says. It goes to a Label. Nothing more. Once there, `cmd` continues "as usual" - line by line. So it does `tzutil /s "Hawaiian Standard Time"` , followed immediately by `tzutil /s "W. Europe Standard Time"`

Also the Expression `'%t%' == '%t%'` seems to be complete nonsense.

Following the logic of your script, it can be simplyfied as:

```
@echo off
set "Programma=C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe"
Start ""  "%Programma%"
tasklist |find /i "%Programma%">nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
  tzutil /s "Hawaiian Standard Time"
) else (
  tzutil /s "W. Europe Standard Time"
)
```

(and you forgot a redirection `>`)

Answer (score 0):

```vb
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions

rem before launching minecraft change the TZ to EU.
tzutil /s "W. Europe Standard Time"

set "Programma=C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft\MinecraftLauncher.exe"
Start ""  "%Programma%"

rem give a break of 3mins before starting the loop
@timeout /T 180 /nobreak >nul

:isrunning
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq MinecraftLauncher.exe" /FI "STATUS eq running" /NH /FO csv | findstr /ic:"MinecraftLauncher.exe" >nul
if errorlevel 0 (
    rem :: Software found, then wait 3 mins before another loop
    @timeout /T 180 /nobreak >nul
    goto isrunning
) else (
    rem :: Software not found, we can now change the TZ before exit.
    tzutil /s "Hawaiian Standard Time"
    exit /b 0
)
```